# Retrieve binary operator called on an instance

Tags: python

I've been mucking around with class special methods to [overload numeric operators](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.7/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types) via `object.__add__(self,other)` etc.

Is there a *generic* way to find out which binary operator was called though?

For unary operators you can use `__getattr__`, e.g:

```
class Test():
  def __getattr__(self, name):
    print name
t = Test()
~t  # prints __invert__
```

but calling binary operators e.g. `t+t` or `t+5` always calls `__coerce__` which looses the info about what the operator is.

---

Solution based on Jochen Ritzel's answer below: the easiest way is to add the following to the above class:

```
def __coerce__(self, other):
  self.other = other    # store 'other' somewhere we can access it
  return None
```

Then `__getattr__` (which gets called after `__coerce__`) has got access to both the operands - as `self` and `self.other`- and the operation - as `name`.

HOWEVER it turns out trying to use dynamic dispatch via `__getattr__` is almost certainly a *really* bad idea compared to just defining the special methods you actually need, as for operators (as opposed to attributes) Python will actually call whatever `__getattr__` returns.

(Hope updating my question is ok, didn't seem to fit in the comment box)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`t+t` calls `__coerce__` and then `__add__`. `__coerce__` is supposed to convert (numeric) types to a common class, for example `1.0 + 2` first coerces both numbers to floats.

If you want to do something special you can return proxy objects from `__coerce__` that see the following operator.